# Python Selenium not loading full page source

Tags: python, selenium, web

The source code from the Selenium web page appears to be incomplete.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.youtube2mp3.cc/')

vid_name = driver.find_element_by_id('input')
vid_name.send_keys('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVbH1BVXywY') 
driver.find_element_by_id('button').click()


element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'download'))
)


url = driver.page_source
url = str(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url,"html.parser")
print(soup)
```

When I access the soup , the href is empty

```
<a href="" id="download" rel="nofollow">Download</a>
```

When I use a time delay it seems to work fine, but I'd like to know how to use WebDriverWait to make sure that the href with id=download loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the `WebDriverWait` wait until the download button has a `href`

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, './/a[@id="download" and @href!=""]'))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube2mp3.cc/")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "download"))
    )
```